# QBit POST method not able to parse plaintext

Tags: java, rest, curl

I'm using Qbit to write a simple REST app, and having trouble getting POST-ed text to be parsed correctly.  This is pretty much [straight out of a tutorial](https://github.com/advantageous/qbit), so I'm not sure what I could be missing

in SimpleService.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/body/string", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public boolean bodyPostString(String body) {
    return body.equals("foo");
}

...

public static void main(final String... args) {

        final ServiceEndpointServer serviceServer = EndpointServerBuilder
            .endpointServerBuilder()
            .setUri("/")
            .build();
    serviceServer.initServices(
            new SimpleService());
    serviceServer.startServer();
```

in terminal

```
 curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d 'foo' http://localhost:8080/service/body/string
```

response

```
["Unable to JSON parse body :: false not parsed properly\n\nThe current character read is 'f' with an int value of 102\nfalse not parsed properly\nline number 1\nindex number 0\nfoo\n^"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with the version of QBit I'm using (0.9.3), however I was able to work around the problem by wrapping my POST body in JSON, and parsing it using [advantageous boon](https://github.com/advantageous/boon) (I assume) as all JSON is handled by QBit.

in a new class, SimpleJSONWrapper:

```
import java.util.Map;

public class SimpleJSONWrapper {

    public final String payload;

    public SimpleJSONWrapper(final String payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
     }

    public String getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }
}
```

and the original bodyPostString method becomes:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/body/string", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public boolean bodyPostString(SimpleJSONWrapper body) {
    return body.getPayload().equals("foo");
}
```

now send your request as:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d '{\"payload\":\"foo\"}' http://localhost:8080/service/body/string
```

note, if you have nested JSON as your payload, you'll need your `SimpleJSONWrapper` to store a `Map<String, Object>`, not a `String`